# Is there a way to find if someone like a facebook page?

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-graph-api-v2.0

I have tried the following: `/{user-id}/likes/{page-id}` (found here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/common-scenarios#pagelikes) but I always get an empty array result, no matter if I use V1 with real user id or V2 with app scoped user IDs.

Is there specific permissions needed for this?

Thank you,
Dan

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's linked in the docs you mentioned that you need the `user_likes` permission to be able to request the

```
/{user-id}/likes/{page-id}
```

See:

- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/common-scenarios#pagelikes
- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.1/user/likes#readperms

Comment: ok, thanks, I hoped that docs was saying that you will need user_likes to get all page likes but you could check one without...

Comment: and of course you can only check for the authorized user, so /me/likes would be good enough. also, please read the platform policy about fan/like gates, they are not allowed anymore.

Comment: Yes, but if he just wants to check a single page, I don't see a reason why he should get the whole page likes (with pagination etc.).. You're right concerning the like gates.